# Atualizar valor JSON com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Como posso atualizar o valor `data.dM`  sem precisar reescrever redefinindo tudo..? quando eu faço `data.dM = 'lalalaa';` o valor nao é atualizado em `data`

```
var data = [{
    "dM": 'lolololo'
}];

data.dM = 'lalalaa';
```

Answer (score 3):

O que você tem aí é uma array, com um (e somente um) objeto dentro. Então você precisa acessar a primeira posição da array antes de poder acessar a propriedade `dM` do objeto:

```
data[0].dM = 'lalalaa';
```

Comment: este zero deve ser usado independentemente da posiçao de dm?

Comment: O zero é a posição do objeto (que contém o `dM`) dentro da array.

Answer (score 2):

Resposta rápida:

```
var data = [{
    "dM": 'lolololo'
}];
    
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        data[i].dM= "dado " + i;
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

---

A resposta @bfavaretto está correta porém para entendê-la precisamos saber alguns conceitos, no exemplo:

```
var alunosSalaAula = [
    {
        "nome": "jaozinho"
    },
    {
        "nome": "mariazinha"
    }
];
```

**- O que temos?**

Um JSON

**- Mas o que é JSON?**

JSON é uma string padronizada para armazenar dados que quando interpretado pelo javascript se torna em arrays e objetos.

**- Então como é a sua estrutura?**

Basicamente quando temos o seguinte JSON temos um array vazio, os colchetes indicam um array

```
[]
```

Quando temos algo entre chaves temos um objeto, no exemplo abaixo temos um array com um objeto dentro que nao tem nenhuma propriedade

```
[{}]
```

O JSON também pode vir com um objeto que tem um array dentro, etc.

```
{pessoas: ["joao", "maria"]}
```

**- Por que preciso saber disso?**

Por que sabendo que um JSON não é nada mais do que arrays e objetos fica fácil; voltando ao exemplo passado se eu tenho um array de objetos alunos como "andar" por eles? ou seja, como andar em um array? Usando for!

```
var alunosSalaAula = [
    {
        "nome": "jaozinho"
    },
    {
        "nome": "mariazinha"
    }
];
for(var i=0; i < alunosSalaAula.length; i++){
    alunosSalaAula[i].nome = "aluno " + i;
}
alert(JSON.stringify(alunosSalaAula));
```

---

Como dito pelo   @bfavaretto o JSON é o objeto no estado de String, que seria algo como

```
var json = '{pessoas: ["joao", "maria"]}';
// convertendo para ojjeto javascript
var objeto = JSON.parse(json);
```

Se você já o tem literalmente, isso não se faz necessário;

Comment: Boa explicação, mas nada disso é json (exceto o que você passa para o alert no final dos exemplos). São objetos e arrays literais. Só se tornam json quando serializados.

Comment: @bfavaretto, sim mas o que ele tem também não é JSON, então imagino que ele saiba converter